# Mysql Results from one table that hasn't been populated in another

Tags: mysql

I would like to get all the results from 1 table that havent been populated in another is this possible in a query? I have been trying with a Left join but with no avail.

Table1: users_postcodes
Field: postcode

Table2: postcodes
Field: postcode

I want to get all the postcodes from table2 which haven't been added to table1.

This is what I have so far, I know for a fact its wrong, but any help would be very helpful:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
t2.`postcode` AS `nouser_postcode` 
FROM `postcodes` AS t1 
LEFT JOIN `users_postcodes` AS t2 on t2.`postcode` != t1.`postcode`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` means "all the records in the LEFT table, any (any) matching records from the right". As written in your query above,  the LEFT table is `postcodes`, since that's in the `FROM` clause. Your joined table, `users_postcodes` is the right handle table.

You actually want a `RIGHT` join instead: all the records from users_postcodes that don't have a matching record in postcodes:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.postcode
FROM postcodes AS t1
RIGHT JOIN users_postcodes AS t2 ON t2.postcode = t1.postcode
WHERE t1.postcode IS NULL
```

This will pull up all records from your users_postcodes table, try to match them against any records in users. However, since you're looking for un-matched records, you use the `WHERE` clause to only return records which DON'T have a value in t1.

Comment: All my results keep coming back as NULL? Well I get 1 result with all columns saying NULL

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all the postcodes from table2 which haven't been added to table1.

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct postcode
FROM t2
WHERE postcode NOT IN (Select postcode from t1)
ORDER BY postcode
```